# OpenGL - Get Real World Coordinate of an object after rotate it

Tags: c, opengl

I have to modify a C program that simulates the solar system in order to set the "eye" ("Camera", Viewport, whatever...) in X planet. The program uses OpenGL. The planets orbit around the sun and that's the main issue. I read all about this, but seems that anybody did this: Get the real position of an object after rotate it.

First, I tested getting the ModelView Matrix.

```
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,jupiter_matrix);
```

Most of the people said that in the position 12, 13 and 14 of the matrix you have the real world position of the object in every moment (Even after you make the transformations), but that isn't true because that coordinates change when I change the viewport using gluLookAt(); so I can't use that.

Second, using my Computer Graphics knowledges I wondered about using the Rotation Matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) and multiply it to the original position of the object (bc I know the angle rotation in every frame). After that, I thought that I finally get the positions of the object in every frame, but that wasn't true bc the coordinates that I had grow more quickly than the real ones so the animation of the camera it's more quickly than the object rotation. Reading about this, I figured out that OpenGL uses other matrix (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml) and I don't know what the hell it's that.

The github repo with the project: https://github.com/delor34n/nemesis_v2/tree/dev

Comment: Scroll down on the wikipedia page, in section "Rotation matrix from axis and angle" there is exactly the matrix given that OpenGL uses.

Comment: Then just get the model matrix isolated from lookAt

Comment: How do you get that matrix? Also BDL, I know which matrix it's, but I don't know how to work with it